# Postgresql query first and last in every range

Tags: postgresql

I have table

| id | machineid | reset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | false |
| 2 | 1 | false |
| 3 | 1 | false |
| 4 | 1 | true |
| 5 | 1 | false |
| 15 | 1 | true |
| 17 | 1 | false |
| 20 | 2 | false |
| 21 | 2 | false |
| 25 | 2 | false |
| 30 | 2 | false |

I cant figure out how to find first and last id for every machine. Reset create new range for next rows. Result should look like:

| machineid | startid | endid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 15 | 17 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 |

Comment: This question is for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start from grouping your records into groups or ranges. As the order of your records matter, it indicates you can make use of [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). You have to determine how you are going to uniquely name these groups. I suggest you use the number of resets above the record. This result to this statement:

```
SELECT *
 , SUM(case when reset then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by machineid order by id) as reset_group
FROM 
  test;
```

After that finding the start and end ids is a simple **GROUP BY** statement:

```
SELECT 
  machineid, MIN(id) as startid, MAX(id) as endid
FROM (
  SELECT machineid, id
   , SUM(case when reset then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by machineid order by id) as reset_group
  FROM 
    test
) as grouped
GROUP BY
  machineid, reset_group
ORDER BY
  machineid, startid;
```

Please try it out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ede3c4bf7b94b1fc4076fe7e8d3736d8)